# I need an help for integrate Stripe in my Ionic Mobile App

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

I'm developing a Taxi Booking Platform on Mobile Hybrid App with Ionic and Firebase.

I need your help to integrate the payment system with Stripe.

I want to create customers automatically and charge only when a client presses the "PAY" button.

Here's the code I already use:

```
$scope.addCard = function () {
Stripe.card.createToken($scope.newCard, function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {

  if (response.error) {
    Toast.error(response.error.message);
  } else {
    // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
    var token = response.id;
    StripeHttp.post('https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/' + customerId  + '/sources', {
      source: token
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      getCards(customerId);
      console.log(reponse.id)
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      Toast.error("Add cards fail. " + status + data);
    });
  }
});
};
```

Comment: So what is the problem? What is the question exactly? What is not working?

Comment: this code work if i set the customerId in variable , My question is i would like create customer automatically in my app , and i would know the solution for create the payment Checkout

Answer (score 0):

As I see from your code, you are not distinguishing between the client-side and server-side.

The code you have displayed should be put on the server, and not in your Ionic app.

There are two ways to overcome your issue:

1. [Host your own Server Side](https://www.noodl.io/market/product/P201512041604740/stripe-payments-kit-server-side-api-to-process-all-payments-with-a-live-example-in-ionic) and make HTTP calls from your Ionic app
2. [Send HTTP calls from your Ionic app](https://www.noodl.io/market/product/P201604181926406/stripe-payments-api-noodlio-pay-the-easiest-way-to-setup-stripe-payments) to an already hosted and free payment server like the [Stripe Payments API](https://market.mashape.com/noodlio/noodlio-pay-smooth-payments-with-stripe)

As for option 2, here are two templates that already integrate and explain how to do that (elaborated docs):

- [If you are interested in an Ionic 1.x template to integrate Stripe,
  then have a look at this starter](https://www.noodl.io/market/product/P201604181926406/stripe-payments-api-noodlio-pay-the-easiest-way-to-setup-stripe-payments).
- [If you are interested in an Ionic 2.x template to integrate Stripe,
  then have a look at this starter](https://www.noodl.io/market/product/P201702241736843/stripe-with-ionic2-quickly-and-easily-integrate-stripe-in-your-ionic2-app).